# How to programmatically inject faults into Pharo methods?

Tags: testing, smalltalk, pharo, fault

I want to inject faults into Pharo methods. Something like

- change `ifTrue:ifFalse:` to `ifFalse:ifTrue:`,
- change `+` to `-`,
- change `and:` to `or:`,

etc.

How could I do this? Are there new/other possibilities in Pharo 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pharo 4 will have a solution for that, but for now you have to do it by hand...

For normal messages like #+, #-, etc... you can modify the literal array of the method, but it won't work for message like #ifTrue:ifFalse: and #ifFalse:ifTrue: because the compiler inlines the code for better performances. One solution is to copy the AST of the method, modify it, compile it and install it in the class. Something like that should work:

```
FaultInjector>>#replace: aSelector with: anotherSelector in: aCompiledMethod
    | newAST |
    "Save the original method to restore it later"
    replacedMethods add: aCompiledMethod.

    "Copy the AST"
    newAST := aCompiledMethod ast copy.

    "Rewriting the AST"
    newAST nodesDo: [ :each | 
        (each isMessage and: [ each selector = aSelector ])
            ifTrue: [ each selector: anotherSelector ] ].

    "Compile the AST and install the new method"
    aCompiledMethod methodClass 
        addSelectorSilently: aCompiledMethod selector 
        withMethod: (newAST generate: aCompiledMethod trailer).
```

Then you should have a method to restore the methods you replaced:

```
FaultInjector>>#restore
    replacedMethods do: [ :each | 
        each methodClass 
            addSelectorSilently: each selector
            withMethod: each ].
    replacedMethods removeAll
```

Comment: Works in Pharo 3 and is very cool! Thank you! (In Pharo 2 RBMethodNode does not yet understand #generate: But that’s just a note, i am fine with Pharo 3)

Answer (score 2):

Once upon a time there were such framework for Squeak, search for MutationTesting

http://www.slideshare.net/esug/mutation-testing

http://www.squeaksource.com/MutationTesting.html

I doubt that it can work as is in Pharo 2.0/3.0, and I don't know if there's already a Pharo port, but it might be worth trying, and in anycase it should be a nice starting point.

Also search for MutationEngine from Hasso Plattner Institute

http://lists.squeakfoundation.org/pipermail/squeak-dev/2012-October/166011.html